# Ignore Propertyname in EF6 Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF6 to insert records to sql database using database first approach.
I have a calculated field in the sql table called `AccountNumber`  so after calling context.Savechanges(), I get an entity validation error event though I dont pass any value to that property in the model `comps`. How do I ignore the AccountNumber property when inserting

```
using (PMMCEntities context = new PMMCEntities())
                    {
                        var comps = new RHEMA_CLIENTS()
                        {
                            //AccountNumber ="",// Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["accno"]),
                            CompanyName = Request.Form["Company"],
                            Location = Request.Form["location"],
                            Address = Request.Form["address"],
                            Telephone1 = Request.Form["tel1"],
                            Telephone2 = Request.Form["tel2"],
                            Email1 = Request.Form["email1"],
                            Email2 = Request.Form["email2"],
                            Website = Request.Form["website"],
                            ContactName = Request.Form["contactname"],
                            ContactPosition = Request.Form["contactname"],
                            ContactPhone = Request.Form["contactphone"],
                            ContactEmail = Request.Form["contactemail"],
                            BusinessRegNo = Request.Form["regno"],
                            TIN = Request.Form["TIN"],
                            LicenseNo = Request.Form["license"],
                            LicenseExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(exp,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            EntityType = Request.Form["entity"],
                            CapitalStructure = Request.Form["capital"],
                            CustomerCategory = Request.Form["category"],
                            CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                            Frozen = frozen
                        };

                        context.RHEMA_CLIENTS.Add(comps);
                        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Do you use an EDMX file?

Comment: Yes please, I use an EDMX file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NotMapped] attribute above your AccountNumber property
As following,

```
[NotMapped]
public <Type> <Name>{get; set; }
```

This might help for DB First
https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/38445897/how-to-exclude-certain-columns-in-ef6-using-database-first-

Comment: Thanks, but since this is database first approach, any changes will be overwritten when the code is regenerated

Comment: The you might need to update model from database, then remove this property manually from model class

Comment: Thanks, but this same property is needed in GET method to retrieve the value in the database  for display

Comment: After the model class is updated, it should work well for retrieval as well

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate the property with [NotMapped] attribute in your entity class.

Comment: Thanks, but since this is database first approach, any changes will be overwritten when the code is regenerated